# Square boxes resize to rectangles on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

This is what I've designed so far. However, when I preview my site on my phone the square boxes get squished up against each other, forming rectangles. How can I get this to display in an optimal manner when previewed from a smaller screen?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code used to display the "Articles" row:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 3%">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
        <h2 class="entry-title">Articles</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="small-9 columns">

        <?php query_posts( array( 'category_name=articles', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) );?>                

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="small-3 columns">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content-box', get_post_format() ); ?>                             
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>              

            <?php endif; ?>

    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily manage to build a grid resizing using media queries.

For example, for screens smaller than 640px, make columns 100%... You can achieve this by creating a breakpoint, and pscifing which CSS rules must chanve below that screen resolution.

Here's an example:

```
.small-9 { width: 40%; } /* At some point, the box will be very small */
```

so... you do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .small-9 { width: 100%; }
}
```

Simple as that. If you don't get it, you can watch some tutorials on responsive design or feel free to leave comments and I'll try better.

Luck!